# Character segmentation in python

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr

I am working on detecting handwritten symbols using computer vision in python. I trained a cnn on a dataset of individual characters, but now I want to be able to extract characters from an image in order to make predictions on the individual characters. What is the best way to do this? The handwritten text that I will be working with will not be cursive and there will be an obvious separation between the characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use find contours and bound them with a box.

```
image = cv2.imread("filename") 
image = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(image,None,10,10,7,21)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

res,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) #threshold 
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3)) 

 dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel,iterations = 5) 

 val,contours, hierarchy = 
            cv2.findContours(dilated,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 

 coord = []
 for contour in contours:  
      [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)   
      if h>300 and w>300:   
          continue   
      if h<40 or w<40:   
          continue  
      coord.append((x,y,w,h)) 

 coord.sort(key=lambda tup:tup[0]) # if the image has only one sentence sort in one axis

 count = 0
 for cor in coord:
        [x,y,w,h] = cor
        t = image[y:y+h,x:x+w,:]
        cv2.imwrite(str(count)+".png",t)
  print("number of char in image:", count)
```

Answer (score 3):

In the below snippet,the boxes variable has dimensions for each character in the image.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

file = '/content/Captchas/image22.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(file)
h, w, _ = img.shape

boxes = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img)

for b in boxes.splitlines():
    b = b.split(' ')
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (int(b[1]), h - int(b[2])), (int(b[3]), h - int(b[4])), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2_imshow(img)
print(boxes)
```